# INSERT data not working? connection works fine with the database

Tags: php, database, postgresql, sql-insert

I try to save the name "one" in the database but it is not working, the echo always returns "not working". With a simple SELECT, it works, so the connection works fine. But the insert does not. Would you see any error in this code? (the last id was 20, so I put 21, but even with null, the result is the same) :

```
<?php
try {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    try {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO person (idperson, name, map) VALUES (21, :name, null)");
        //$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if ( $stmt->execute() ){
            echo "worked!";
        }
        else {
            echo "not working";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $ee){
        echo 'Error : '.$ee->getMessage().'<br />';
        echo 'N° : '.$ee->getCode();
    }

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Error : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
       echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();
}
?>
```

But the SELECT works :

```
//this works
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM person WHERE idperson=1");
$stmt->execute();
while($lines = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo $lines->name.'<br />';
}
```

And the postGreSQL :

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
  idperson integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying(50),
  map bytea,
  CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idperson)
)
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure the user you use has WRITE rights in it's profile?

Comment: Please see the echo is blank which is syntax error i think so in else condition of your insert code else {
        echo "not working";
        echo 
    }

Comment: Try $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name,PDO::PARAM_STR); and remove the unwwanted echo in else loop

Comment: Thanks for the comments, no it still does not work, I edited my post above. I am using localhost, so I don't know what you mean @Allendar by the WRITE rights?

Comment: You're always using a "user" (e.a. `root`) to access your database. If the user you are using doesn't have WRITE permissions you can't do anything with INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/etc. You should see it in the error-message tho.

Comment: OK thanks, the user is the owner postgres, so I guess it lets me use the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start to try/catch the exception before the **prepare()** and after it.

```
$name = $_GET['name'];

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO person (idperson, name, map) VALUES (21, :name, null)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(Exception $ee){
    echo 'Error : '.$ee->getMessage().'<br />';
    echo 'N° : '.$ee->getCode();
}
```

do it and see what's the problem

Comment: thanks, it does not work though. I edited my post above. I can't see what is wrong...

Comment: So the answer was index 21 was already taken, but it did not show up in the database, I had to restart the software and check the error with `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` . Thanks for the help anyway